# How to perform Update Operation in Spring Batch ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring, itemwriter

I am writing a spring batch job wherein ItemReader I am reading from the database and apply some rules in Processor and want to update in ItemWriter.

I could not able to figure it out how to perform update operation in ItemWriter class.

I tried to set the datasource with update statement and I dont know how to pass the primary key here to update the records

Comment: Are you using a custom itemwriter or one that is provided by Spring Batch? Please share your code to be able to help you.

Comment: The one which is provided by Spring Batch

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to set the datasource with update statement and I dont know how to pass the primary key here to update the records

You can pass parameters to your query using a `ItemPreparedStatementSetter`. Here is an example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilderTests.java#L148-L166

You can also use an "update" SQL statement as well:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilderTests.java#L135